# Difference in time stamps between /proc/uptime and dmesg

Tags: linux, time, kernel, uptime, dmesg

Today I noticed an issue with the timestamps in my Linux box running redhat 7.3. The timestamp as shown in dmesg is behind of the one shown in /proc/uptime

```
# echo TEST > /dev/kmsg &&  dmesg | tail -1 && cat /proc/uptime
  [661503.956980] TEST
  661301.99 15107232.56
```

As I understand, they both shows the number of seconds passed since the kernel initialized. Then what could be causing the difference here ?

Answer (score 0):

dmesg timestamps show CLOCK_MONOTONIC, while /proc/uptime shows CLOCK_BOOTTIME.

See 'man timer_create' for details on what CLOCK_* is.

Comment: Do you have any reference in the kernel sources that shows that the printk uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC?

Comment: To be exact, printk timestamps use sched_clock(), which is kernel-internal timer that never stops and is not corrected by ntp or whatever.  It is not directly available to userspace though, CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the closest match what userspace can observe.

Comment: Yeah, I [had followed that up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77772306/how-does-one-get-the-current-time-as-dmesg-would-print-it) in the kernel source myself meanwhile (IIRC, `sched_clock()` is called by `local_clock()`.
It's weird however, how do `dmesg`, `journalctl` etc. convert to proper times, if nothing in userspace can get `sched_clock()`?!
Or do they all just show wrong times then.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this CLOCK_MONOTONIC current value?

Comment: man clock_gettime

Answer (score 0):

They are different clocks.

- The timestamps of kernel dmesg are retrieved by kernel internal
  local_clock(), which is not exported to userspace. It's not
  CLOCK_MONOTONIC nor CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW.
- The time shown in /proc/uptime is CLOCK_BOOTTIME. CLOCK_BOOTTIME is
  identical to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, except that it also includes any time
  that the system is suspended.

On x86, these two clocks are usually both based on tsc clock. But they are managed independently.